# Do OAuth2 access token can only be used once?

Tags: swift, networking, oauth-2.0, alamofire

So in my project i need to use oauth2 to access my user's reddit data. the problem is once the token is used it cannot be reused again and i have to retrieve new access token. I always thought token can be used again and again until it expired. Is this correct or there is a mistake in my code?

Comment: i think there's a mistake .. it can be used unitl it not expired OR you do a new login ..che if your code is doing a new login every time or the token expiration

Comment: Are you following https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2 closely?

Comment: I see, maybe there is a mistake in my code. When first I get the access token I saved it using https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess.  And then retrieved it later in different place. could this keychain dont return a string value?